# Grant data only access in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, privileges

I want to be able to create an SQL login (or role) that will be able to:

- Read data
- Write data

And will not be able to change anything to the schema (alter tables, columns, keys, etc).
I know there is a way to do this with a script (cursor + setting deny / grant permissions for the login to each database).

This doesn't cut it as it has to be repeated each time a database is added to the server. I want the permissions to apply to newly created databases as well at minimum in the following cases:

- A database is manually created
- A database is restored from .bak as a new database
- A database is imported from bacpac

Because this will be used in development mode only - hacks / workarounds are acceptable as well.

Comment: db_datareader, db_datawriter

Comment: Thanks, I also found that those are the roles I need, however, the more important thing is how to automatically apply them to a given user in all cases a database is created on the Server (via create new database, restore from bak as a new database or via new bacpac import).

Answer (score 1):

Adding the user with the required permissions to the `model` database will ensure that it is added to all newly created databases on that instance. You will need to use a script to add the user to existing databases & also any databases that you migrate to the instance (e.g. via backup & restore). You can find more information on the `model` database [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/model-database).

Comment: Very useful to know about the model database and this seems to address most of the cases, but not all of them (looks like it will work if I create a new databsase, but not if I restore a new database from backup / bacpac). If this is the case and for the sake of the answer completeness - is there a place a script can be written to address any DB creation (either by backup restore as a new database or bacpac import). Maybe I can write a trigger there and this will address all cases?

Comment: The model database won't affect restored databases. Pinal Dave has a script that might be of use to you in that case - it adds a user for all databases on a server that don't already contain the use: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/03/09/sql-server-how-to-add-user-across-databases/

You could add this script as a step in your restore process or create a SQL Agent job that runs the script regularly to check for databases without the user.